# Maven build war need to deploy on Weblogic 12.2.x using jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, weblogic

I am trying to deploy war file on weblogic using jenkins. For this I am using Weblogic deployer plugin in jenkins. I have configured everything in the jenkins but while deploying the war it always failing. The only thing I am figure out is that my actual war file name is 'xxx.3.0.0.war' but in weblogic it is taking 'xxx.3.0'.Please find image for jenkins weblogic deployer plugin configuration. [image: Please find image for jenkins weblogic deployer plugin configuration.]  Please help

Below are the weblogic deployment logs :

```
------------------------------------  ARTIFACT UNDEPLOYMENT ------------------------------------------------
weblogic.Deployer invoked with options:  -debug -remote -verbose -noexit -name psm-web-3.0 -targets DevServer -adminurl t3://localhost:7001 -user weblogic -undeploy
[WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.<init>():119] : Constructing DeploymentManager for J2EE version V1_4 deployments
[WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.getNewConnection():162] : Connecting to admin server at localhost:7001, as user weblogic
[ServerConnectionImpl.getEnvironment():295] : setting environment
[ServerConnectionImpl.getEnvironment():298] : getting context using t3://localhost:7001
[ServerConnectionImpl.getMBeanServer():246] : Connecting to MBeanServer at service:jmx:t3://localhost:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime
[ServerConnectionImpl.getMBeanServer():246] : Connecting to MBeanServer at service:jmx:t3://localhost:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime
[DomainManager.resetDomain():36] : Getting new domain
[DomainManager.resetDomain():39] : Using pending domain: true
[MBeanCache.addNotificationListener():96] : Adding notification listener for weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache@5fdcaa40
[MBeanCache.addNotificationListener():107] : Disabling mbean caching due to: java.io.InvalidClassException: weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -355364455225633633, local class serialVersionUID = -6063846258165761631
[MBeanCache.addNotificationListener():96] : Adding notification listener for weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.ModuleCache@36902638
[MBeanCache.addNotificationListener():103] : Added notification listener for weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.ModuleCache@36902638
[ServerConnectionImpl.initialize():178] : Connected to WLS domain: base_domain
[ServerConnectionImpl.init():168] : Initializing ServerConnection : weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl@f6efaab
[BasicOperation.dumpTmids():740] : Incoming tmids:
[BasicOperation.dumpTmids():742] :   {Target=DevServer, WebLogicTargetType=server, Name=psm-web-3.0}, targeted=true
[BasicOperation.deriveAppName():143] : appname established as: psm-web-3.0
<Dec 5, 2019 5:05:52 PM IST> <Info> <J2EE Deployment SPI> <BEA-260121> <Initiating undeploy operation for application, psm-web-3.0 [archive: null], to DevServer .> 
[BasicOperation.dumpTmids():740] : Incoming tmids:
[BasicOperation.dumpTmids():742] :   {Target=DevServer, WebLogicTargetType=server, Name=psm-web-3.0}, targeted=true
[BasicOperation.loadGeneralOptions():655] : Delete Files:false
Timeout :3600000
Targets: 
DevServer
ModuleTargets={}
SubModuleTargets={}
}
Files: 
null
Deployment Plan: null
App root: null
App config: null
Deployment Options: {isRetireGracefully=true,isGracefulProductionToAdmin=false,isGracefulIgnoreSessions=false,rmiGracePeriod=-1,retireTimeoutSecs=-1,undeployAllVersions=false,archiveVersion=null,planVersion=null,isLibrary=false,libSpecVersion=null,libImplVersion=null,stageMode=null,clusterTimeout=3600000,altDD=null,altWlsDD=null,name=psm-web-3.0,securityModel=null,securityValidationEnabled=false,versionIdentifier=null,isTestMode=false,forceUndeployTimeout=0,defaultSubmoduleTargets=true,timeout=0,deploymentPrincipalName=null,useExpiredLock=falsespecifiedTargetsOnly=false}

[BasicOperation.execute():472] : Initiating undeploy operation for app, psm-web-3.0, on targets:
[BasicOperation.execute():474] :    DevServer
weblogic.management.ManagementException: [Deployer:149001]No application named "psm-web-3.0" exists for operation "undeploy".
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.adminserver.operations.OperationHelper.assertAppIsNonNull(OperationHelper.java:968)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.adminserver.operations.RemoveOperation.updateConfiguration(RemoveOperation.java:191)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.adminserver.operations.AbstractOperation.updateConfigurationAndInitializeDeployment(AbstractOperation.java:478)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.adminserver.operations.AbstractOperation.execute(AbstractOperation.java:301)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.adminserver.operations.RemoveOperation.execute(RemoveOperation.java:84)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeployerRuntimeImpl$2.run(DeployerRuntimeImpl.java:1034)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:137)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeployerRuntimeImpl.performDeployerActions(DeployerRuntimeImpl.java:1028)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeployerRuntimeImpl.undeploy(DeployerRuntimeImpl.java:513)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.modelmbean.WLSModelMBean.invoke(WLSModelMBean.java:532)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$21.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:589)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:587)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXContextInterceptor.invoke(JMXContextInterceptor.java:249)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$21.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:589)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:587)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityMBeanMgmtOpsInterceptor.invoke(SecurityMBeanMgmtOpsInterceptor.java:65)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$21.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:589)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:587)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:439)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$21.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:589)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:587)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.MBeanCICInterceptor.invoke(MBeanCICInterceptor.java:301)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$21.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:589)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:587)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.PartitionJMXInterceptor.invoke(PartitionJMXInterceptor.java:435)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime.internal.FederatedMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(FederatedMBeanServerInterceptor.java:355)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$21.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:589)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:587)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.CallerPartitionContextInterceptor.invoke(CallerPartitionContextInterceptor.java:217)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServer.invoke(WLSMBeanServer.java:327)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder$11$1.run(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:655)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder$11.run(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:653)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:368)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.invoke(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:646)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1471)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1312)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1411)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:645)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$2.run(BasicServerRef.java:534)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:368)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:163)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:531)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:138)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
[ServerConnectionImpl.close():341] : Closing DM connection
[ServerConnectionImpl.close():361] : Unregistered all listeners
[ServerConnectionImpl.closeJMX():381] : Closed JMX connection
[ServerConnectionImpl.closeJMX():393] : Closed Runtime JMX connection
[ServerConnectionImpl.closeJMX():405] : Closed Edit JMX connection
Unexpected Error Initializing Deployer: weblogic.management.ManagementException: [Deployer:149001]No application named "psm-web-3.0" exists for operation "undeploy".
------------------------------------  ARTIFACT DEPLOYMENT ------------------------------------------------
weblogic.Deployer invoked with options:  -debug -stage -remote -verbose -upload -name psm-web-3.0 -source C:\Users\AA00599156\.jenkins\customwar\psm-web-3.0.0.war -targets DevServer -adminurl t3://localhost:7001 -user weblogic -deploy
[WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.<init>():119] : Constructing DeploymentManager for J2EE version V1_4 deployments
[WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.getNewConnection():162] : Connecting to admin server at localhost:7001, as user weblogic
[ServerConnectionImpl.getEnvironment():295] : setting environment
[ServerConnectionImpl.getEnvironment():298] : getting context using t3://localhost:7001
[ServerConnectionImpl.getMBeanServer():246] : Connecting to MBeanServer at service:jmx:t3://localhost:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime
[ServerConnectionImpl.getMBeanServer():246] : Connecting to MBeanServer at service:jmx:t3://localhost:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime
[DomainManager.resetDomain():36] : Getting new domain
[DomainManager.resetDomain():39] : Using pending domain: false
[MBeanCache.addNotificationListener():96] : Adding notification listener for weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache@5fdcaa40
[MBeanCache.addNotificationListener():107] : Disabling mbean caching due to: java.io.InvalidClassException: weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -355364455225633633, local class serialVersionUID = -6063846258165761631
[MBeanCache.addNotificationListener():96] : Adding notification listener for weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.ModuleCache@36902638
[MBeanCache.addNotificationListener():103] : Added notification listener for weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.ModuleCache@36902638
[ServerConnectionImpl.initialize():178] : Connected to WLS domain: base_domain
[ServerConnectionImpl.setRemote():489] : Running in remote mode
[ServerConnectionImpl.init():168] : Initializing ServerConnection : weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl@f6efaab
[BasicOperation.dumpTmids():740] : Incoming tmids:
[BasicOperation.dumpTmids():742] :   {Target=DevServer, WebLogicTargetType=server, Name=psm-web-3.0}, targeted=true
[BasicOperation.deriveAppName():143] : appname established as: psm-web-3.0
<Dec 5, 2019 5:06:02 PM IST> <Info> <J2EE Deployment SPI> <BEA-260121> <Initiating deploy operation for application, psm-web-3.0 [archive: C:\Users\AA00599156\.jenkins\customwar\psm-web-3.0.0.war], to DevServer .> 
[BasicOperation.dumpTmids():740] : Incoming tmids:
[BasicOperation.dumpTmids():742] :   {Target=DevServer, WebLogicTargetType=server, Name=psm-web-3.0}, targeted=true
[BasicOperation.loadGeneralOptions():655] : Delete Files:false
Timeout :3600000
Targets: 
DevServer
ModuleTargets={}
SubModuleTargets={}
}
Files: 
null
Deployment Plan: null
App root: C:\Users\AA0059~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AA00599156\.\config\deployments\psm-web-3.0
App config: C:\Users\AA0059~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AA00599156\.\config\deployments\psm-web-3.0\plan
Deployment Options: {isRetireGracefully=true,isGracefulProductionToAdmin=false,isGracefulIgnoreSessions=false,rmiGracePeriod=-1,retireTimeoutSecs=-1,undeployAllVersions=false,archiveVersion=null,planVersion=null,isLibrary=false,libSpecVersion=null,libImplVersion=null,stageMode=stage,clusterTimeout=3600000,altDD=null,altWlsDD=null,name=psm-web-3.0,securityModel=null,securityValidationEnabled=false,versionIdentifier=null,isTestMode=false,forceUndeployTimeout=0,defaultSubmoduleTargets=true,timeout=0,deploymentPrincipalName=null,useExpiredLock=falsespecifiedTargetsOnly=false}

[ServerConnectionImpl.upload():862] : Uploaded app to D:\VHA\Software\Oracle2\user_projects\domains\base_domain\.\servers\DevServer\upload\psm-web-3.0
[BasicOperation.execute():472] : Initiating deploy operation for app, psm-web-3.0, on targets:
[BasicOperation.execute():474] :    DevServer
Task 5 initiated: [Deployer:149026]deploy application psm-web-3.0 on DevServer.
dumping Exception stack
Task 5 failed: [Deployer:149026]deploy application psm-web-3.0 on DevServer.
Target state: deploy failed on Server DevServer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysema.query.dml.UpdateClause
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:89)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:53)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getFields(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:1047)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getFields(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:1041)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:145)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.J2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(J2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:47)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:120)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.PojoAnnotationProcessorImpl.processJ2eeAnnotations(PojoAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:93)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.processAnnotations(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:304)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.processPOJOsInModuleScopes(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:229)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.prepare(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:73)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:241)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:229)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:103)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:242)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:800)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1352)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:270)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:177)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:186)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:47)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)


Target Assignments:
+ psm-web-3.0  DevServer
[ServerConnectionImpl.close():341] : Closing DM connection
[ServerConnectionImpl.close():361] : Unregistered all listeners
[ServerConnectionImpl.closeJMX():381] : Closed JMX connection
[ServerConnectionImpl.closeJMX():393] : Closed Runtime JMX connection
[ServerConnectionImpl.closeJMX():405] : Closed Edit JMX connection
```

Comment: I could see 2 issues in the output:
1. First it's trying to deploy the application which is not available.
2. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysema.query.dml.UpdateClause

You need to fix the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: Hi Naveen, Yes i can see those but while installing war directly from console, weblogic is not giving any error . And also about application which is not available, i am not sure why it trim the war file name

Comment: It's not trimming the war file name. It's taking application name without .war extension. But it's strange that why it's working fine when deployed via console and giving error when deployed using weblogic.Deployer plugin. You tried via console in same environment I believe.

Comment: Also look like Jenkins trying to undeploy the application before deploying it.